# Where does IDispatchEx exists?

Tags: c#, interop

Can't find the library which contains IDispatchEx interface. I want to implement this interface, but can't find it. 
Does anyone knows where it is?

Thanks,
Paul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write a managed class that implements the [IDispatchEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sky96ah7(VS.85).aspx) interface you will first need to define this interface because it does not exist in .NET. Here's a [link](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid620085F6ECBCC8F7C598BC99A9B97BB756514DFE.aspx?s=zoom#L1136) to its definition. IMHO implementing this interface won't be a trivial task.

Comment: I was recently looking for `IDispatchEx` interop definition and wrapper for C# and couldn't find any, the link in this answer appears to have gone. So I had to create it from scratch, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18546866/1768303) in case someone may need it.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do? Is this for use inside C#? Or from outside (COM)?

If you just want browser support, then perhaps host in `WebBrowser` and set the [`ObjectForScripting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx).

You can *sort of* add methods to a type in C# 3.0 with extension methods:

```
public static void Bar(this Foo foo, int someArg) {...}
....
Foo foo = ...
foo.Bar(123);
```

But this is still static-typed. C# 4.0 introduces `dynamic` for true dynamic objects inside the CLR/DLR, but you'd implement `IDynamicObject`. And it isn't trivial.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to emulate unexisted property(or method) in my C# class when its called from javascript. For example,
var o=new ActiveXObject('object');
o.Foo("hi");
Please note that Foo method doesnt exists in my C# class. So I want to impelement IExpando.AddMethod to achieve my goal.

Comment: But with IExpando.AddMethod I have some troubles - it doesn't invokes when unexisted method called. But it works well when unexisted field called (I mean IExpando.AddField fired). So I can't figure the difference and want to try IDispatchEx interface.